# Error catching exception in Anko async call (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm calling an async call using Retrofit inside an Anko doAsync call. The problem is that I don't know how to catch the IOException that throws the `execute()` properly, basically the execute call is not getting called. If I comment the `if (resultBody is T)` line, and put the call inside a `trycatch` it works like a charm. Anyone knows why?

```
doAsync {

    val response = call.execute()

    uiThread {

        if (response.isSuccessful) {

            val resultBody = response.body()

            if (resultBody is T)
                callback.onSuccess(resultBody)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doAsync docs:

> - @param exceptionHandler optional exception handler.   *  If
>     defined, any exceptions thrown inside [task] will be passed to it. If
>     not, exceptions will be ignored.

Looks like you can pass an `exceptionHandler` to manage them or it will handle exceptions with their `crashLogger`:

```
private val crashLogger = { throwable : Throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace() }

//...

fun <T> T.doAsync( //...
    exceptionHandler: ((Throwable) -> Unit)? = crashLogger,
    //... )
```

You can check [Anko doAsync implementation](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/7febda295f683349e3a1b3f9d999e4faa362b8cd/anko/library/static/common/src/Async.kt#L133) for details.